# Html5 elements in .md file

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I have a static html file with animations and different html5 tags. Is it possible to include this file (will all resources, images, js) in a jekyl blog post/page. More specifically, from .md file can I use include tag to use my static html5 file. I am very new to both jekyl, markdown. thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTML file can be included in Jekyll like this:

```
{% include note.html %}
```

And it will load the file located at `_includes/note.html`. Or you can use relative directories to the one that is calling the include, for example, consider having `index.md` and we want to include another html file inside it called `note.html`:

Folder structure:

```
.
├── note.html
└── index.md
```

Then in `index.md`:

```
---
title: example
---

{% include_relative note.html %}
```

And when you access `index.md` it will display the content of `note.html`.

Comment: thnx, I was actually trying to find if there are ways to add html5 tags. I tried to include my file but all the formats got broken.

Comment: then you should include the code causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Markdown doesn't allow all html tags, you can take a look [here](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) to see which html tags are allowed and how to type them in markdown

for animations if you can wrap your animation in a gif then you can use it in markdown like so

```
![](http://i.imgur.com/OUkLi.gif)
```

and if you want to add a still image like so

```
![](http://i.imgur.com/Ssfp7.png)
```